# Published content changes are not reflecting on site. But could see the changes in web . Only after app pool recycle changes are reflecting on site

Tags: publishing

I am using `Sitecore 8.2 update 7` version. What ever content we are adding/modifying and publishing. Changes are not reflecting on site. But changes can see in web DB. After IIS App pool recycles, changes are reflecting on site.

Site is deployed On-Premises, Not sure whether CM and CD sites are on the same server. It's happening in the Staging environment.

**Checked below checklist**

1. EnabledEventQueue is true in `Sitecore.config`
2. Added handler for `Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer` for publish:end and 
   publish:end:remote  events.
3. `ScalabilitySettings.config` is enabled on both CM and CD.
4. Checked Scalability guide, All checklist has been taken care.

But still not sure what would be the issue. Please help me to solve this issue.

Any suggestion is most appreciated!!.

Comment: Are you clearing the HTML caches for the relevant sites?

Comment: Yes Mark , I am doing that using sitecore admin page.

Comment: Have you tried clear the sitecore cache manually from the cache.aspx page on CD?

Comment: Is your data coming from search indexes? Is it coming by Sitecore API? Do you have other type of caching like Item or Data Cache?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I have used one  custom index  to list and search the products its working fine.  Using Sitecore api to fetch the content from respective db. Not used any custom caching mechanism